# Setting getKeyRouteName dependant on route (web or api)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

Tried looking for the answer to this everywhere but having no luck so far...

Basically I want my web route to use a slug for its URL, but I want to use ID for the API route. So...

http://myurl.com/chapter/my-chapter-slug

and

http://myurl.com/api/chapter/1234

Have tried various combinations of things in the getRouteKeyName method (if(Request::route()->named('myapiroute'), if(Request::isJson() etc...) but I think these might be being checked against the page it's running on, rather than the route I'm trying to generate?

I'm thinking maybe I need to extend the base model to have a separate one to use with my API maybe?

So I'd have...

```
class Chapter extends Model
{
    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'slug';
    }
    ....
}
```

and then...

```
class ApiChapter extends Chapter
{
    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'id';
    }
    ....
}
```

But not sure how I'd structure this in the most "Laravel" way? Or is there a better/tidier solution?

Answer (score 0):

define your route for example like

```
Route::get('chapters/{chapter}','ChapterController@show'); // find by slug
Route::get('api/chapters/{chapter}','ApiChapterController@show'); // find by id
```

for web controller

```
class ChapterController extends Controller
{

   public function show(Request $request,$slug)
   {
      $instance =  Model::whereSlug($slug)->first();

   }
}
```

for api

```
   class ApiChapterController extends Controller
{

   public function show(Request $request,$id)
   {
      $instance =  Model::find($id);

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define 2 different routes for that but unfortunatelly you will not be able to use model binding and you will have to look for the model like:

```
 public function show(Request $request,$slug) {
      $instance =  Model::whereSlug($slug)->first();
   }
```

as shown below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48115385/6525417